# Mongodb local database files size/amount explodes

Tags: disk-space-utilization, mongodb

I have three replicasets for my shard, but I noticed that the [local database](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/About+the+local+database) on each replicaset-node has produced a lot of local.* datafiles. The disk where mongodb is storing the datafiles is ~50G in size, but the local.* datafiles take up to 22G. The actual data don't need one gb at all (for now). I read the [Excessive Disk Space](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space) article, where it states that the local-db should only take up to 5% of disk space.

I still don't know if I should set the `--oplogSize`, the `-fallocate` or the `--noprealloc` switch, and how it affect the other replicated databases.

```
# ll mongo -h
total 23G
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  64M Mar 26 10:20 test.0
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 128M Mar  1 14:03 test.1
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  16M Mar 26 10:19 test.ns
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  64M Mar 26 10:20 production.0
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 128M Feb 29 18:28 production.1
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  16M Mar 23 17:39 production.ns
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongod mongod 4.0K Feb 29 18:28 journal
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  64M Feb 29 18:01 local.0
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 128M Feb 29 18:00 local.1
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Feb 29 18:00 local.10
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Feb 29 18:00 local.11
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Mar 26 10:20 local.12
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Mar 26 10:20 local.2
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Feb 29 18:00 local.3
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Feb 29 18:00 local.4
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Feb 29 18:00 local.5
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Feb 29 18:00 local.6
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Feb 29 18:00 local.7
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Feb 29 18:00 local.8
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod 2.0G Feb 29 18:00 local.9
-rw------- 1 mongod mongod  16M Mar 26 10:19 local.ns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mongod mongod    6 Feb 29 18:01 mongod.lock
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongod mongod 4.0K Mar  1 14:03 _tmp
```

I'm using mongodb 2.0.4 on centos 6.2/64bit.

Update: When I query the collection oplog.rs in the local db I get this:

```
PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.count();
130234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I looked at the wrong row in df. `/` is 50G, but the data is stored in another mounted volume where we have 1.8 T, so the 5% rule makes sense now (meaning it could still grow up to ~90G). So I will use the `--oplogSize` parameter, since this size is a bit overkill for our usecase.

(However, it seems that the --oplogSize can't change the size of existing logs, I have to check if I can delete those files first).

Comment: hehe i asked in comment how big is hdd then remove the comment :D

Comment: Yes, I noted it, but it disappeared when I wanted to upvote it :)

Comment: be careful about the --oplogSize parameter, besides it being important that it is big enough to cover any downtime for replication, it is not simple to change the size once it already exists.  See the post here for details: http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2011/02/22/resizing-your-oplog/

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior in MongoDB. Mongo server reserves some of the disk space right after installation.